# Importing an RGBA image from raw binary data?

Tags: image-processing

**Problem:** I have printed some binary data from gdb which I'd like to inspect as an image.  I am able to do this with `gimp` if I parse the data as an RGBA raw image with width 251 and height 261.  However, I'd like to use Wolfram to do this programatically.

I have tried

```
Import["/path/to/my/raw/image.bin", {"RawBitMap", 
  "Summary"}, ImageSize -> 251]
```

which almost works.  The issue is that it parses as an RGB file (without an alpha channel), and so the image is totally corrupted.

**Question:** Is this possible in Wolfram?

Comment: It's definitely possible, perhaps using `BinaryReadList`. It's hard to be more specific without an example file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This import format seems to be rather inflexible. The documentation, says,

> Stores images as RGB or grayscale bitmaps at a resolution of 8 bits per channel.

Thus I would not bother with it.

Import as `"Binary"`, use `Partition` to put the data into the desired form, then use `Image` to create the final image.  I used something like this for a 150 by 150 image:

```
data = 
  ArrayReshape[
    Import["~/Downloads/r.rbm", "Binary"],
    {150, 150, 4}
  ];

Image[data, "Byte", ColorSpace -> "RGB"]
```

Comment: You could use `ArrayReshape[data, {150,150,4}]` instead of two partitions, and `"ColorSpace"->"RGB"` can be `ColorSpace->"RGB"` without the quotes around the option.

Comment: @flinty Thank you, this is much better. The answer is now updated.

Comment: You can also use [`BinaryReadList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BinaryReadList.html) for the first step to gain some speed.

Comment: @all: This question has morphed to a new one with more subtlety around the arguments: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/236640/parsing-raw-pixel-data-as-a-wolfram-image    I was curious if you had any thoughts on it?