# Parsing raw pixel data as a Wolfram Image

Tags: import, image

**Context.** I have a C++ function which receives pixel `data` (along with `width`, `height`, `stride`). I have dumped this data to a file and I am trying to use Wolfram to inspect it; however, this requires I parse it *exactly* as was intended to, and I'm having trouble doing this.

Here is the function in question:

```
bool WlrGLES3Texture::wlr_texture_write_pixels(
    struct wlr_texture *_texture, uint32_t stride,
    uint32_t width, uint32_t height,
    uint32_t src_x, uint32_t src_y, uint32_t dst_x, uint32_t dst_y,
    const void *data) {

  glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

  glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, stride / 4);
  glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, src_x);
  glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, src_y);

  glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, dst_x, dst_y, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

  //…

}
```

Notice also the `dst_x`, `dst_y`, `src_x`, and `src_y` paramaters. According to OpenGL documentation, this is what these mean:

```
//GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS (src_x) and GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS (src_y)
These values are provided as a convenience to the programmer; they provide no functionality that cannot be duplicated by incrementing the pointer passed to glTexImage1D, glTexImage2D, glTexSubImage1D or glTexSubImage2D. Setting GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS to i is equivalent to incrementing the pointer by in components or indices, where n is the number of components or indices in each pixel. Setting GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS to j is equivalent to incrementing the pointer by jk components or indices, where k is the number of components or indices per row, as just computed in the GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH section.


//glTexSubImage2D documentation:
xoffset (dst_x)
  Specifies a texel offset in the x direction within the texture array.

yoffset (dst_y)
  Specifies a texel offset in the y direction within the texture array.
```

Finally, here is my draft Wolfram function:

```
importImageBinary[pathToPixelData_, width_, height_, stride_, srcX_, srcY_, dstX_, dstY_] := 
  Image[ArrayReshape[Import[pathToPixelData, "Binary"], {height, width, 4}], 
   "Byte", ColorSpace -> "RGB"]
```

**Problem:** As you can see, it doesn't yet accomodate for the `srcX`, `srcY`, `dstX`, and `dstY` arguments. And it seems to work for only *some* binary files (and I think it's only the files where `srcX == srcY == dstX == dstY == 0`? Also, it's not accomodating for `stride` either, which I think is a mistake!

**Question:** How do I imporove my Wolfram function to work with this data?

---

**EDIT:** Here is a link to a working and non-working case.

- binary data: [working.bin](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/george.w.singer/trash/wlr_texture_write_pixels.1004.251.261.0.0.0.0x7f897cbe2000.bin)
- `width` is `251`, `height` is `261`, `stride` is `1004`, and `dstX == dstY == srcX == srcY == 0`
- Result of import using my draft function:

[image]

Here is a non-working case.

- binary data: [non-working.bin](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/george.w.singer/trash/wlr_texture_write_pixels.4096.297.238.116.185.116.185.0x7f897c241000.bin)
- `width` is `297`, `height` is `238`, `stride` is `4096`, `srcX` is `116`, `srcY` is `185`, `dstX` is `116`, `dstY` is `185`
- Result of import using my draft function:

[image]

Comment: I get a usable image by doing `ArrayReshape[data, {Length@data/stride/4,stride,4}]`, where `data` is the imported list of bytes. You'll probably have to describe the intended functionality of the other parameters 
in more detail though: The entire image seems to be one continuous piece, so I'm not sure what to make of the other parameters.